# Как реализовать всплывающее окно?

Tags: jquery-ui, ajax, html, css, javascript

Приведите пример, как реализовать всплывающее окно, вместо того чтоб после выполнение чего-либо не было направление на страницу с текстовым сообщением. Например, после нажатие кнопки отправить, выходило на той же странице всплывающее окно с сообщением "Отправлено" и после чего происходило простое обновление страницы.

Comment: также модально окно можно реализовать на css

Comment: Так же, можно посмотреть в сторону jQuery dialog. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ там и примеры есть. )

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример. У нас есть скрытый блок с текстом сообщения, по щелчку на кнопку вешается дополнительный класс на скрытый блок с свойством `display: block` при помощи jQuery.

```js
$('.btn').click(function () {
  $('.popup').addClass('popup_state_acitve')
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: pink;
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.popup_state_acitve {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque pariatur odit vitae magnam neque modi cupiditate ad, blanditiis quod excepturi magni aut, nulla quia sequi cum. Esse, praesentium? Distinctio!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque pariatur odit vitae magnam neque modi cupiditate ad, blanditiis quod excepturi magni aut, nulla quia sequi cum. Esse, praesentium? Distinctio!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque pariatur odit vitae magnam neque modi cupiditate ad, blanditiis quod excepturi magni aut, nulla quia sequi cum. Esse, praesentium? Distinctio!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque pariatur odit vitae magnam neque modi cupiditate ad, blanditiis quod excepturi magni aut, nulla quia sequi cum. Esse, praesentium? Distinctio!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque pariatur odit vitae magnam neque modi cupiditate ad, blanditiis quod excepturi magni aut, nulla quia sequi cum. Esse, praesentium? Distinctio!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque pariatur odit vitae magnam neque modi cupiditate ad, blanditiis quod excepturi magni aut, nulla quia sequi cum. Esse, praesentium? Distinctio!</div>
  <button class="btn">Оправить</button>    
</div>
<div class="popup">
  Отправлено
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/d-batmanov/pen/WEzEgY